# How to extract Value from key in Linux

Tags: linux, shell

"AccessKey":"asdasdgfdfsd","secretAccessKey":"asdggrt233434" 
I want to extract values for AccessKey and secretAccessKey in linux shell.

Comment: Which Linux shell? And why Linux specifically? Most (all?) shells run on other OSes, too. Why does it have to be the shell? What format is this data in? Is it JSON?

Comment: yeah it is json. 
"AccessKey":"asdasdgfdfsd","secretAccessKey":"asdggrt233434"  I have data in this format "KEY":"VALUE". I need to extract value for key in linux. Please help me with some commands

Comment: What is the exact format of your input text? Is it just a single line? with same format? `"key":"value","key":"value"` ? If that is your entire text you can use `cut` to find the values.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Yes @BlackPearl it is the same format. Can you please share the command.

Comment: take a look at [tag:jq], it's not a good idea to parse JSON using line oriented tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is to use jq. But if it should be quick&dirty, the following lines may help:

```
#!/bin/bash

Extract() {
    sed -e "s/\"/'/g" -e "s/.*'$1':'\([^']*\)'.*/\1/" data.json
}

SecretAccessKey=$(Extract "SecretAccessKey")
SessionToken=$(Extract "SessionToken")
AccessKeyId=$(Extract "AccessKeyId")
```

Comment: Can you please also provide me to extract the IP address between double quotes. I am bit weak at regex. [ "164.53.64.22" ]

Comment: you mean somthing like that? `echo '[ "164.53.64.22" ]' | sed 's/.*"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/'`

Answer (score 0):

One simple way of doing it is just by using cut

keys.data

```
{"AsummedRoleUser":{"AssumedRoleId":"rolenewtemp:testing","Arn":"arn:aws:sts::5335323242:assumed-role/testing/testrole"},"Credentials":{"SecretAccessKey":"asdgerdadadad","SessionToken":"Afdfddeeradasdsdasd","AccessKeyId":"Asafsdfasdasd"}
```

Getting keys using cut

```
accessKey=$(cat keys.data | cut -d',' -f1 | cut -d'"' -f4)
secretAccessKey=$(cat keys.data | cut -d',' -f2 | cut -d'"' -f4)
```

But this can fail in many cases. For one, if there is any `"` or `,` inside the keys. It can also fail if the order of the keys are changed. You should properly prefer proper key-value parsing.

EDIT: The proper way to parse your type of data is by using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

`cat keys.data | jq '.Credentials .SecretAccessKey'` will give you the `SecretAccessKey`

`cat keys.data | jq '.Credentials .AccessKeyId'` will give you the `AccessKeyId`

Comment: Any more suggesstion please. where I can pass the accessKey in the command and it will return the value associated with it. Also I will read a file

Comment: This is just a very rough solution, in case you just have 1 single line as you mentioned. If you have more data in a file, you should prefer some proper JSON parser like jq, as @oguz suggested. Anyways, it would be more helpful if you add more context to your question, like the exact content format of the file.

Comment: {"AsummedRoleUser":{"AssumedRoleId":"rolenewtemp:testing","Arn":"arn:aws:sts::5335323242:assumed-role/testing/testrole"},"Credentials":{"SecretAccessKey":"asdgerdadadad","SessionToken":"Afdfddeeradasdsdasd","AccessKeyId":"Asafsdfasdasd"}} this is the exact format and I need values for SecretAccessKey, AccessKeyId and SessionToken. this output is stored in a text file

Comment: Can you please tell me how can we hide the argument pass with the script. I am executing below script.     sh /opt/tomcat/test.sh 'JAMES' 'new123'      In this JAMES and new123 are my user and password. how can I hide this in the console ???. Like when I hit this command, I should get something like this sh /opt/tomcat/test.sh '****' '****' or any better solution.